# In GA360 Bigquery data, how are user visits broken into GA360 sesions?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Unsure of how GA360 breaks up user visits into sessions. We have session timeout set up for 30 minutes. However, notice that there are a large number of visitors that have multiple visits (and corresponding bigquery rows) inside 30 minutes.

For example, the below query yields a large fraction of our total visitors having the earliest visit start time and latest visit start time falling within a 30 minute window:

```
  FullVisitorId,
  min(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(VisitStartTime)) as first_time,
  max(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(VisitStartTime)) as last_time,
  (max(VisitStartTime) - min(VisitStartTime)) / 60 as time_diff_min, 
  count(*) as visitcount
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  FullVisitorId in 
  (SELECT FullVisitorId from `project.dataset.124196983.ga_sessions_*` GROUP BY FullVisitorId HAVING count(*) > 1)
GROUP BY 
  FullVisitorId
HAVING
  time_diff_min < 30
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods by which a session ends:

1. Time-based expiration:

   - After 30 minutes of inactivity
   - At midnight
2. Campaign change:

   - If a user arrives via one campaign, leaves, and then comes back via a different campaign.

So looking at the 30 minutes wouldn't be enough to count the number of sessions.

You can find the official documentation here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565